# Kotlin + Compose for desktop: different use/import of libraries between executed code and compiled .msi code

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, desktop-application, moshi, jetbrains-compose

In my project I'm using these library imports:

```
implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0")
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.3")
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.3")
```

to make rest api calls.
the dto classes I use (using only these libraries) are of the type

```
import com.squareup.moshi.Json

data class myClassDto(
   @field:Json(name = "api_wanted_name1") val myName1: String,
   @field:Json(name = "api_wanted_name2") val myName2: Int,

)
```

and so on, while to create the retrofit object that will make the usage calls

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
   .baseUrl("https://my_apy_url")
   .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
   .build()   
   .create()
```

When I run the code from the IDE everything works fine.
When I compile and launch the .msi it gives me the following error:

```
Unable to create converter for class .. at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:54)
at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createResponseConverter(HttpServiceMethod.java:126)
at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(HttpServiceMethod.java:85)
at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:39)
at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:202)
at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:160)
```

looking at the error I realized that it is as if this library had also been imported to me

```
com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.14.0
```

which I have to make some changes in my code:

1. I have to add the builder to the retrofit object:

```
val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()
```

and therefore it becomes me

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
   .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
   .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
   .build()
   .create()
```

2. all my dto classes I have to become

```
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass
    
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
    

data class myClassDto(
   val api_wanted_name1: String,
   val api_wanted_name2: Int
)
```

so I have to add @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true) in front of the class and the variable names must be like the ones I used before inside @field:Json("") which I can no longer use.

**That said, the problem is solvable, but I have to modify a lot of dto classes.**
**Is there a way to solve this problem? can you tell me why this happens?**